# Responsividade em iframes

Tags: javascript, html

Atualmente estou usando esse código para definir o height de um iframe:

Iframe:

```
<iframe class="rastreamento" style="width: 100%; border: none;" src=">meutarget<" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Só que no mobile não funciona, fica menor do que deveria ficar e como o desativei o scroll no style, fica impossível visualizar todo conteúdo.

Qual a melhor forma de resolver isso?

Comment: Olha , eu consideraria utilizar um Bootstrap para fazer a maior parte de responsividade , e nas gafs q podem haver , utilizar ou o proprio JS como vc ja ta fazendo ou o CSS msm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para deixar ele responsivo, use o evento `onresize` no objeto `window` enviando o iframe para a função `resizeIframe`, assim como fez no atributo `onload`. Só que em vez de enviar `this`, pode selecionar o iframe com `document.querySelector`.

Desta forma, sempre que a janela do navegador sofrer alterações de tamanho (no caso do mobile, ao alternar a orientação do dispositivo) será recalculado o `height` do iframe:

```
window.onresize = function(){
   resizeIframe(document.querySelector("iframe"));
}
```